# Azure AD Not Syncing Mail Attribute Correctly

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Let me preface this by saying I'm not that familiar at all with Azure AD, and that this is basically something I've inherited.

We have Azure AD Sync set up to sync our on-premises AD to Azure.

We've recently upgraded our SSO solution, and it's now authenticating against Azure AD. We've ran into a problem as not all of our users attributes are syncing correctly.

All these users have their on-premises mail attribute set in the form of:
jdoe@subdomain.domain.com

However, for a majority of our users that we've tracked down to, anyone created after 2018/2019 does not sync their mail attribute to this format. Instead, their mail attribute in Azure is set in the following format:
SamAccountName@domain.com

Note that for our users SamAccountName and their mail attribute do differ in the format used for the naming schema.

Now, for those who were created pre 2018/2019, their mail attribute in Azure is syncing properly in the format of:
jdoe@subdomain.domain.com

The only thing we can think of is that pre that date, we had been using one automated solution to generate our users accounts, and then post that date we switched to a different provider.

That new generation process includes a once a day provisioning of accounts into Office365.

We need these attributes to be sync'd correctly with the jdoe@subdomain.domain.com format in order to work with one of our SSO integrations.

Any thoughts on what the issue is and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

After some testing, it was determined that licensing for Office365 is the culprit.

When we would assign our users licensing (Specifically Office 365 A1 for students), the following two applications would cause the overwrite of that attribute:
Information Barriers
Exchange Online

As long as the user is not licensed for those applications, everything works as expected.